# cakephp validation with another model

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new to cakephp and working on version 1.3. I am trying to validate the form from controller but it doesn't work. Here is my controller's action code :
Controller is cards_controller.php

```
class CardsController extends AppController {

            var $name = 'Cards';
            var $uses = array('Customfield','Customer','Parameter','Merchant','Merchantcard','Merchantcustomfield','Cardexist','Country','State','Customercontacts','Cardrenew');
            var $helpers =  array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript');
            var $components = array('Session','RequestHandler','RequestHandler','Auth');

    function index()
    {

    }



 function renewCard()
        {

         if($_SESSION['Auth']['User']['id'] == "")
                    {
                       $this->redirect("../users/login");
                    }

            $this->loadModel('Cardrenew');  

            $this->Cardrenew->set(array(
                      "customer_id" =>$id,
                       "merchant_id" =>$this->data['Card']['merchant_id'],
                       "merchant_card_id" =>$this->data['Card']
                                        ));                                  

                       if($this->Cardrenew->save())
                       {

                       }  
        }
    }


and here is the model code : 



class Cardrenew extends AppModel
    {
     public $name = "prc_renewal_cards";
     var $validate = array(
     'merchant_id' => array(
     'nameRule2'=>array(
     'rule'=> array('check'),
     'required' => true,
     'message'=>'Card already exists.'
     )),

    'nameOnCard' => array(
    'alphaNumeric' => array(
    'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9 ]*$/i',  // only 3 char (int or char  , no spaces in string)
    'required' => true,
    'allowEmpty'    => false,
    'message' => 'Please enter alphabets and numbers only.'
    ))

    );
```

Controller does not saves any values as the nameOnCard is required. Means validation happens but it does not show any error messsages. The same thig I have applied on the another action in the same controller with different model name, it works fine there. Then what happens for this action?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions

- var $uses is bad mojo, use model associations (belongsTo, hasMany, etc)
- use Auth for session management, you can read sessions with $this->Session->read() http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1250/Authentication

public $name = "prc_renewal_cards"; should actually be public $name = "Cardrenew";

Showing your view code would be helpful.